# Terminology: probabilistic generalisations of substitutions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, terminology

We write $\mathbb{D}(A)$ for the set of all discrete  probability distributions over $A$, in other words, all functions $d : A \rightarrow [0, 1]$ that sum up to 1, i.e. $\Sigma_{a \in A}d(a) = 1$. (Note the question can easily be generalised to arbitrary probability distributions.)

Let $\mathbb{P}$ be a probability distribution on $X$, i.e. a member of $\mathbb{D}(X)$.
If $S \subseteq X$ and $\mathbb{P}_S$ is a probability
distribution on $S$, in other words, a member of $\mathbb{D}(S)$, we define the *substitution of $\mathbb{P}_S$ for $S$ in $\mathbb{P}$*, written
$\mathbb{P}[\mathbb{P}_S/S]$, as the following member of $\mathbb{D}(X)$.

$$
x
\mapsto
\begin{cases}
  \mathbb{P}[S] \cdot \mathbb{P}_{S}(x) & x \in S\\
  \mathbb{P}(x) &  \text{else}
\end{cases}
$$

This is a highly natural construction when thinking about probabilistic algorithms, so I imagine it has come up before (think about generalising assignments like `x := 17`, where all, memory, `x` and the value assigned, are drawn according to distributions).

**Question:** Is this construction of new probability distributions from old known and named in probability theory?

Comment: When you write $A$, do you mean a finite alphabet?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur No. In principle $A$ could be any set. If the set is too big, we need to use a  measurable space with a suitable $\sigma$-algebra. I've formulated the question assuming the discrete  $\sigma$-algebra for simplicity of presentation. In my use case, $S$ is finite. If there are any gotchas arising from size or non-measurable sets that would also be interesting.